# How to load javascript that does not block rendering?? How to load after full page has been painted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser

I am loading the chat service called drift. I am getting very bad score on PageSpeed mobile because of this only. I want to load it so it does not block rendering and like should start after whole page is painted. 
If you want to consider the website here it is:
https://stockarea-application-test.herokuapp.com

I have tried to use async and defer to load the javascript file but both of them are blocking the render. ( I checked that thing over pagespeed insights recommendation).

I also have used jquery $.getScript() after document ready function but still its showing render blocking

Please I really need some help on how I could solve it. Some things on internet says about worker files but they don't have DOM apis on them so can't use them as this drift service do paint somethings on DOM. so please help

Comment: `async` won't work for inline scripts, only external ones. ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script))

Comment: hey @ChrisG let me try doing with src attribute

Comment: hey @ChrisG its still showing the same thing, I made a file named drift.js having drift code and now calling this file with src attribute and async but still getting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I think what you tried is only let the script load asynchronously, but because processing the script must be in the only main thread, the only way not to block your business code is putting the third-party script in a frame if it can be. ( or wait a long timeout and execute the code quietly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use async and defer method with jQuery. But better than async and defer attributes, in this way you can load javascript after the browser has finished loading resources on the page.

When the browser has finished loading resources on the page, it fires the load event. And you can tell the browser to wait to load scripts until that happens.

Here's how to do that with jQuery :

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("body").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='some-javascript.js'>") //Load js after rendered 
});
```

You can also do with native javascript :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src = "some-javascript.js" //Load js after rendered 
    document.body.appendChild(script)
});
```

In this way, it creates the script element after the resources have been loaded.

Comment: Sorry, its not wokring... In fact javascript execution time has increased now.

Comment: It loads javascript at last. So, it might not block rendering.